# ObseservableCollection not getting populated correctly using foreach (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, foreach, observablecollection

I use an array and foreach to fill up a list. But the WPF GUI only shows me the last item from the array and not all of them. The binding is correct, there must be a logical error in my code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }

string[] clients = { 
            "XYZ.company.server",
            "ABC.company.server"
}

foreach (string item in clients)
{
    Client client = new Client(item);
    Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
    Clients.Add(client);
}

this.DataContext = this;
```

The Gui only shows  "ABC.company.server" on the ListView.

Comment: You're re-creating `Clients` on each loop iteration. Put `Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>()` before the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare collection before loop. So while looping your collection will add items from `foreach` loop.

```
Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
foreach (string item in clients)
{
    Client client = new Client(item);

    Clients.Add(client);

}
```

Otherwise, your collection will be recreated each time in loop and all previous iterated items will not be added into newly created collection.